# How can I handle the empty case in Elixir/Phoenix templates?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a template I have an iteration over some days in an itinerary:

```
<%= for day <- @days do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= day.number %></td>
    <td><%= day.main_event_time %></td>
    <td><%= day.main_event %></td>
    <td><%= day.location %></td>
    <td><%= day.who %></td>
    <td><%= day.summary %></td>
    <td><%= day.lodging %></td>

    <td><%= link "Show", to: day_path(@conn, :show, day) %></td>
    <td><%= link "Edit", to: day_path(@conn, :edit, day) %></td>
    <td><%= link "Delete", to: day_path(@conn, :delete, day), method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'd like have a different message come up in the case when there are no days yet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer versions of Phoenix that support HEEx templates (v1.6 and greater), you can use the `:if` attribute to do this:

```html
<div :if={Enum.empty?(@days)}>
  No days yet.
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can put this before or after your `for` comprehension:

```
<%= if Enum.empty?(@days) do %>
  No days yet.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Got it. The full code is `<%= if Enum.empty?(@days) do %> No days yet <% else %> <%= for day <- @days do %> ... <% end %> <% end %>`.

Comment: @ijt you can put the `for` comprehension in the `else` part, but it is not strictly necessary. When the list is empty, the `for` comprehension will render nothing, no matter where you put it.

Comment: The idea here is to handle the empty case specially. It looks odd to have the table show up with just the column headers and nothing in it.

Comment: I got that, it was part of your original question. All I mean is that you don't really need the `else`, but it doesn't hurt either.